# Does SonarScanner for MsBuild respect web.config?

Tags: c#, msbuild, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

I have configured SonarQube to scan my C# solution and it has raised [S3330](https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/RSPEC-3330) which says that my cookies do not have HttpOnly set

Well, looking at the code only this is an accurate statement. But in fact, I have

```
<httpCookies httpOnlyCookies="true" />
```

in my Web.config which makes all custom cookies http-only. Thus, it seems like SonarScanner is ignoring this setting.

Is there any way to make it respect this setting of web.config?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately not. The SonarC#/VB analyzers only look at the source code files currently.

If you want to stop the issue being reported then your options are to mark the instance of the issue as a false positive in SonarQube, or disable the rule entirely in the Quality Profile.

You could [report](https://community.sonarsource.com/c/bug/fp/7) this false positive to the SonarSource development team; they might be able to improve the rule.

Comment: That's sad but thanks for confirming. Raised [a ticket on SonarSource](https://community.sonarsource.com/t/sonarscanner-for-msbuild-ignores-web-config-for-s3330-httponly-of-cookies/23622)